# Load TreeStore at once. Extjs 4

Tags: extjs, tree

My question is: How can I load the TreeStore at once? 
Because right now, if I'm using proxy, to get Tree after rendering, when I expand the leaf, there is one more request with GET parameter `'node'` - the id of leaf node. So I need to response with the tree of this leaf. but I want to load ALL tree at once and no more requests for that tree.

Right now I have below code:

```
    Ext.define('AdminPanel.TreeNavigation', {              
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',  
        fields: ['id', 'text', 'leaf', 'children']  
    });


    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {

                    model: 'AdminPanel.TreeNavigation',  

                    proxy: {  
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url : 'admin/getTreeNav',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'result'
                        }
                    },

                    root: {
                        expanded: true
                    }

                });
```

Comment: The same question was resolved in this thread: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?237870-Load-TreeStore-at-once.-Etxjs-4&p=873775#post873775

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In store I set the reader root as 'result'.

But in the json_data I've sent the 'children' attribute, like that:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "text": "\u041d\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438",
        "leaf": true,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "text": "\u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u0438",
        "leaf": true,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "text": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0438",
        "leaf": true,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "lang",
        "text": "\u042f\u0437\u044b\u043a",
        "leaf": false,
        "children": [{
            "text": "\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0442\u044b",
            "leaf": true,
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}
```

But needed like this:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "text": "\u041d\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438",
        "leaf": true,
        "result": []
    }, {
        "text": "\u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u0438",
        "leaf": true,
        "result": []
    }, {
        "text": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0438",
        "leaf": true,
        "result": []
    }, {
        "id": "lang",
        "text": "\u042f\u0437\u044b\u043a",
        "leaf": false,
        "result": [{
            "text": "\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0442\u044b",
            "leaf": true,
            "result": []
        }]
    }]
}
```

So, Tree will load all data at the TreePanel.

Answer (score 0):

You need the children nodes to be sent up from the server in the children array recursively.
You do not need leaf and children attributes on the model as the model will be automatically wrapped with the NodeInterface class that will have those and more attributes (see API for the full attribute list)